# how to support Arabic language in generating a word document using Openxml?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

Here is a piece of code that I'm using to generate a word document using Openxml, it works perfectly but it does not support Arabic language although I used the character encoding UTF-8 but its not helping!

I appreciate any help, Thank you!

## region Word document generation code

```
   private void AddParts(WordprocessingDocument parent,string strHeader,string strBody, string strFooter)
   {
       var mainDocumentPart = parent.AddMainDocumentPart();

       GenerateMainDocumentPart().Save(mainDocumentPart);

       var documentSettingsPart =
           mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart
           <DocumentSettingsPart>("rId1");

       GenerateDocumentSettingsPart().Save(documentSettingsPart);

       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head></head><body>" + strBody + "</body></html>"));

       AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = mainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
              AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, "body");

       // Feed HTML data into format import part (chunk).
       formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
       AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
       altChunk.Id = "body";

       mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

       AddHeaderAndFooter(mainDocumentPart, strHeader, strFooter);
   }
   private Document GenerateMainDocumentPart()
   {

       var element =
           new Document(
               new Body(
                   new Paragraph(
                       new Run(
                           new Text(""))
                   ),
                   new SectionProperties(
                       new HeaderReference()
                       {
                           Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                           Id = "rId2"
                       },
                       new FooterReference()
                       {
                           Type = HeaderFooterValues.First,
                           Id = "rId3"
                       },

                       new HeaderReference()
                       {
                           Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default,
                           Id = "rId6"
                       },
                       new FooterReference()
                       {
                           Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default,
                           Id = "rId7"
                       },
                       new PageMargin()
                       {
                           Top = 1440,
                           Right = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                           Bottom = 1440,
                           Left = (UInt32Value)1440UL,
                           Header = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                           Footer = (UInt32Value)720UL,
                           Gutter = (UInt32Value)0UL
                       },
                       new TitlePage()
                   )));

       return element;
   }
   private Settings GenerateDocumentSettingsPart()
   {
       var element =
           new Settings(new EvenAndOddHeaders());

       return element;
   }
   private void AddHeaderAndFooter(MainDocumentPart mainPart,string strHeader,string strFooter)
   {
       // Delete the existing header and footer parts
       mainPart.DeleteParts(mainPart.HeaderParts);
       mainPart.DeleteParts(mainPart.FooterParts);

       // Create a new header and footer parts for first and default pages
       HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
       //HeaderPart headerPart2 = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
       FooterPart footerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();
       HeaderPart defaultHeaderPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
       FooterPart defaultFooterPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<FooterPart>();

       GenerateHeaderPartContentFirst(headerPart,strHeader);
       GenerateHeaderPartContent(defaultHeaderPart);
      // GenerateHeaderPart2Content(headerPart);
       GenerateFooterPartContentFirst(footerPart,strFooter);
       GenerateFooterPartContent(defaultFooterPart);
       //string rId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
       // Get Id of the headerPart and footer parts
       string headerPartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
       string footerPartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(footerPart);
       string defaultHeaderPartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(defaultHeaderPart);
       string defaultFooterPartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(defaultFooterPart);

       // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
       IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

       foreach (var section in sections)
       {
           // Delete existing references to headers and footers
           section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
           section.RemoveAllChildren<FooterReference>();
           section.RemoveAllChildren<TitlePage>();

           // Create the new header and footer reference node
           section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First });
           section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = defaultHeaderPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
           //section.PrependChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = rId, Type=HeaderFooterValues.First });
           section.PrependChild<FooterReference>(new FooterReference() { Id = footerPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First });
           section.PrependChild<FooterReference>(new FooterReference() { Id = defaultFooterPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
           section.PrependChild<TitlePage>(new TitlePage());
       }
       mainPart.Document.Save();
   }
   private void GenerateHeaderPartContent(HeaderPart part)
   {
       Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

       Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };
       Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
       ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
       ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

       paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

       Run run1 = new Run();
       Text text1 = new Text();
       
       text1.Text = "Default Header";

       run1.Append(text1);
       
       paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
       paragraph1.Append(run1);

       header1.Append(paragraph1);

       part.Header = header1;
   }
   private void GenerateHeaderPartContentFirst(HeaderPart part,string strHeader)
   {
       Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

       Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };
       Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph();
       ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
       ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

       paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);




       paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strHeader));


       AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = part.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
           AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, "heder");

       formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
       AltChunk chunk = new AltChunk() { Id = "heder" };
       header1.Append(chunk);

       part.Header = header1;
   }
   private void GenerateFooterPartContentFirst(FooterPart part,string strFooter)
   {
       Footer footer1 = new Footer() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

       Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

       ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
       ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" };

       paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);


       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strFooter));


       AlternativeFormatImportPart formatImportPart = part.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
           AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html, "footer");

       formatImportPart.FeedData(ms);
       AltChunk chunk = new AltChunk() { Id = "footer" };
       footer1.Append(chunk);

       part.Footer = footer1;
   }
   private void GenerateFooterPartContent(FooterPart part)
   {
       Footer footer1 = new Footer() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
       footer1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");

       Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00164C17", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00164C17" };

       ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
       ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Footer" };

       paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

       Run run1 = new Run();
       Text text1 = new Text();
       text1.Text = " Default Footer";

       run1.Append(text1);

       paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
       paragraph1.Append(run1);

       footer1.Append(paragraph1);

       part.Footer = footer1;
   }
   private void GenerateHeaderPart2Content(HeaderPart headerPart1)
   {
       Header header1 = new Header() { MCAttributes = new MarkupCompatibilityAttributes() { Ignorable = "w14 wp14" } };
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpc", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("mc", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w14", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wpi", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");
       header1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape");
       Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "00BE49A6", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00BE49A6" };

       ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
       ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "Header" };

       paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);

       Run run1 = new Run();
       RunProperties runProperties1 = new RunProperties();
       NoProof noProof1 = new NoProof();

       runProperties1.Append(noProof1);

       Picture picture1 = new Picture();

       V.Shapetype shapetype1 = new V.Shapetype() { Id = "_x0000_t136", CoordinateSize = "21600,21600", OptionalNumber = 136, Adjustment = "10800", EdgePath = "m@7,l@8,m@5,21600l@6,21600e" };
       V.Formulas formulas1 = new V.Formulas();
       V.Formula formula1 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum #0 0 10800" };
       V.Formula formula2 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "prod #0 2 1" };
       V.Formula formula3 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum 21600 0 @1" };
       V.Formula formula4 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum 0 0 @2" };
       V.Formula formula5 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum 21600 0 @3" };
       V.Formula formula6 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "if @0 @3 0" };
       V.Formula formula7 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "if @0 21600 @1" };
       V.Formula formula8 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "if @0 0 @2" };
       V.Formula formula9 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "if @0 @4 21600" };
       V.Formula formula10 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "mid @5 @6" };
       V.Formula formula11 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "mid @8 @5" };
       V.Formula formula12 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "mid @7 @8" };
       V.Formula formula13 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "mid @6 @7" };
       V.Formula formula14 = new V.Formula() { Equation = "sum @6 0 @5" };

       formulas1.Append(formula1);
       formulas1.Append(formula2);
       formulas1.Append(formula3);
       formulas1.Append(formula4);
       formulas1.Append(formula5);
       formulas1.Append(formula6);
       formulas1.Append(formula7);
       formulas1.Append(formula8);
       formulas1.Append(formula9);
       formulas1.Append(formula10);
       formulas1.Append(formula11);
       formulas1.Append(formula12);
       formulas1.Append(formula13);
       formulas1.Append(formula14);
       V.Path path1 = new V.Path() { AllowTextPath = true, ConnectionPointType = Ovml.ConnectValues.Custom, ConnectionPoints = "@9,0;@10,10800;@11,21600;@12,10800", ConnectAngles = "270,180,90,0" };
       V.TextPath textPath1 = new V.TextPath() { On = true, FitShape = true };

       V.ShapeHandles shapeHandles1 = new V.ShapeHandles();
       V.ShapeHandle shapeHandle1 = new V.ShapeHandle() { Position = "#0,bottomRight", XRange = "6629,14971" };

       shapeHandles1.Append(shapeHandle1);
       Ovml.Lock lock1 = new Ovml.Lock() { Extension = V.ExtensionHandlingBehaviorValues.Edit, TextLock = true, ShapeType = true };
       shapetype1.Append(formulas1);
       shapetype1.Append(path1);
       shapetype1.Append(textPath1);
       shapetype1.Append(shapeHandles1);
       shapetype1.Append(lock1);
       V.Shape shape1 = new V.Shape() { Id = "PowerPlusWaterMarkObject74287736", Style = "position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:412.4pt;height:247.45pt;rotation:315;z-index:-251653120;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin", OptionalString = "_x0000_s2051", AllowInCell = false, FillColor = "silver", Stroked = false, Type = "#_x0000_t136" };
       V.Fill fill1 = new V.Fill() { Opacity = ".5" };
       V.TextPath textPath2 = new V.TextPath() { Style = "font-family:\"Calibri\";font-size:1pt", String = "Draft" };
       shape1.Append(fill1);
       shape1.Append(textPath2);

       picture1.Append(shapetype1);
       picture1.Append(shape1);

       run1.Append(runProperties1);
       run1.Append(picture1);

       paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties1);
       paragraph2.Append(run1);

       header1.Append(paragraph2);

       headerPart1.Header = header1;
   }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Did you got a reversed characters?

Comment: Take a look at this API documentation it may help you 
http://officeopenxml.com/WPtextFonts.php

Comment: @CodeInNet no I got symbols